# mdadm raid5 disk disabled, state clean, smart passed

Tags: hard-drive, mdadm, raid5

i'm running a raid5 array with 5 disks. One disk got disabled.

**dmesg** :

```
...
[Tue Dec  5 01:02:08 2017] md/raid:md0: read error NOT corrected!! (sector 15263288 on sdb1).
[Tue Dec  5 01:02:50 2017] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#4 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[Tue Dec  5 01:02:50 2017] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#4 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] [descriptor] 
[Tue Dec  5 01:02:50 2017] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#4 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[Tue Dec  5 01:02:50 2017] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#4 CDB: Synchronize Cache(10) 35 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[Tue Dec  5 01:02:50 2017] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 2064
[Tue Dec  5 01:02:50 2017] md/raid:md0: Disk failure on sdb1, disabling device.
[Tue Dec  5 01:02:50 2017]  disk 0, o:0, dev:sdb1
[Tue Dec  5 01:03:10 2017]  disk 0, o:0, dev:sdb1
```

**mdadm -D /dev/md0**

```
    Version : 1.2
Creation Time : Mon Oct 17 14:21:51 2016
   Raid Level : raid5
   Array Size : 5860147200 (5588.67 GiB 6000.79 GB)
Used Dev Size : 1953382400 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
 Raid Devices : 4
Total Devices : 5
  Persistence : Superblock is persistent

Intent Bitmap : Internal

  Update Time : Wed Dec  6 10:06:21 2017
        State : clean
Active Devices : 4
Working Devices : 4
Failed Devices : 1
Spare Devices : 0

       Layout : left-symmetric
   Chunk Size : 512K

         Name : ...:0  (local to host ...)
         UUID : 141ffb01:9780e780:ea038a51:55a98453
       Events : 57755

  Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
     5       8      113        0      active sync   /dev/sdh1
     1       8       33        1      active sync   /dev/sdc1
     2       8       49        2      active sync   /dev/sdd1
     4       8       97        3      active sync   /dev/sdg1

   0       8       17        -      faulty   /dev/sdb1
```

smartctl -H /dev/sdb

```
=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
```

How to deal with this ... remove the device and add it again?

```
mdadm /dev/md0 --remove /dev/sdb1
mdadm /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdb1
```